# Create a Hudson job with Hudson down?

Tags: java, eclipse, hudson, jobs

is there a way to create and build a Hudson job without having Hudson running. Using Hudson Java sources seemed an appropriate solution for me first, but i started having troubles when trying the import onto Eclipse. I've already tried the Hudson tutorial [here](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Setting+up+Eclipse+to+build+Hudson) but started having problems with svn download.

Anybody knows a simpler way to run Hudson from Eclipse and try to debug on it ?

Please help.. and thanks in advance.

Comment: If "without Hudson running" means, that you do not have Hudson installation, but want to build some Hudson job urgently, you may start Hudson locally with "java -jar hudson.war", and start your job there.

Comment: Are you looking to do some Hudson development or to simply use it?

Comment: Thanx Kel for your answer, unfortunately, that's not what i am looking for.

Comment: @Bernard: I am trying to include hudson's mechanism of creating and building a job in our company's framework. That means means we will have Maven written projects that will be built by hudson, but without using the hudson's interface. Like in hudson i will have a button "create a job" and "launch a build", that's why i need to know how do Hudson work, and use its classes/methods to do that.

Comment: Perhaps you will need to utilize Hudson's Remote API: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Remote+access+API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you only need to build the job once or only on demand? What other functionality than just building do you need (e.g. reporting capabilities)? Sounds as if the best solution for you would be to run a branded version of Hudson (so that it fits to the corporate look and feel) and connect it to your user directory. Don't know how the best way of branding would be, have a look at the exploded war file.

BTW, can you describe in more detail, what you want to do. Just saying, that you want to have a create button and a launch build button doesn't really tell us much.

In that case you don't need more than to run "mvn clean install" on the command line and parse the output, to see if it was successful or not. You don't even have to mess around with the Hudson source code.

Another option is to hire one of the developers (e.g. Kohsuke) and pay him some money to do the basic work for you or give you a good start. It will save you a lot of time and might therefore be cheaper for your company.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, i finally got to build my jobs in the classic way, using the hudson-cli and running hudson in background on a different port (so it can't be seen).